# How to get a file in sub folder in Responsive File Manager plugin with TinyMCE Editor?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm using Responsive File Manager plugin for TinyMCe editor it is work very well.

My issue I can't select any images or file in sub folder or directory it is work only in first directory.

Here is Javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?PHP echo base_url('assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js'); ?>"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
       tinymce.init({
       selector: "textarea",
       theme: "modern",
//     base_url:false,
       external_filemanager_path: "/cootel/filemanager/",
       filemanager_title: "Responsive Filemanager",
       external_plugins: {"filemanager": "<?PHP echo base_url('../filemanager/plugin.min.js') ?>"},
       relative_urls: false,
       plugins: [
       "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
       "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
       "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
       "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern responsivefilemanager"//imagetools
       ],
   toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
   toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
// imagetools_cors_hosts: ['mydomain.com', 'otherdomain.com'],
   image_advtab: true,
   templates: [
         {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},
         {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}
              ]
     });</script>
```

My Configuration

```
    'upload_dir' => '/cootel/assets/img/editor/',
    'current_path' => '../assets/img/editor/',
    'thumbs_base_path' => '../assets/img/thumbs/',
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I'm running through the same here...

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your browser, the latest Google Chrome worked best for me.

Comment: Everything is work but when I create any folder and subfolder than i selected that images but the I can't get the url of current of that images